# Convert to_timestamp in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Lets do the following:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1453336500)::date
```

Then i get a date `2016-01-21`

How does the function work backwards. With the date as input and the number (i guess seconds from 1970) as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `extract`:

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM current_timestamp);
```